# Send FCM Notification to multiple users using their UID through cloud functions

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

i have users Uid in an 'users' array as ['uid1','uid2'] now i will be sending notifications to these users in cloud function?

```
        exports.sendNotificationFromCr = functions.database.ref('/cr/{crUid}/notifications/{notificationid}/').onWrite(event => {

    const uid = ['uid1','uid2']; // some how i get this.
    // some work to send notifications
    // to all tokens of uid1 and uid2.    
}
```

here is the database structure:

```
users/
   uid1/
      name:{name}
      FCM-key/
         token1:true
         token2:true
   uid2/
      ...
      FCM-key/
         token3:true
```

using ['uid1','uid2'] i want to send notification to all 3 tokens in my database. how to do that?

Comment: As a starting point, you could use some of [this code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L38-L83) from the [Firebase Cloud Messaging Sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications).

Comment: bob, i have no experience of javaScript so i dont get what is happening here. i learn things from examples but there is only one example. i am able to get 'uid1' and 'uid2' from changing this code but now i have no idea to how to send notifications to all the tokens of these users.

Comment: If you want to use Cloud Functions, you're definitely going to need to learn JavaScript.

Comment: yeah but that will make my project late. i wish they had Java or any other language support in cloud functions :/

Answer (score -1):

If you're using something like firebase. Then you would want to have a notifications database model, that has the userId, the notification title, body and perhaps image, also a seen flag (true or false).

You would then post notifications either from your clients or from your cloud server code into the database. One per client/notification. If you have thousands of users you would use some sort of server-side cronjob, to offload this so that it runs outside of say your client to server API.

On the clients, you would be listening for new rows in that model filtering on the userId and when they appear, display them to the client in your UI. Once the client has seen the notification you would mark it as seen on the client.

Without knowing what platforms, code base, DB you are using it's impossible to explain in code terms how this would be done.

There are various API's for IOS and Android and Firebase that resolve this.

Comment: not exactly what i asked for. i am specific about firebase/google cloud functions. i want the code which is able to send notifications to these users using firebase/google cloud functions.